# Javafx split pane with treeview

Tags: javafx

Please help me to add item from `addproject` controller to project controller. I want to add item from addprojects controller to `projectscontroller` method. Please guide me to resolve this. please guide to dynamically change the right side split pane view and add tree item in treeview and show to user.

```
    package com.define.controller;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;

    import java.util.ResourceBundle;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javafx.event.Event;

    //import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

    import javafx.scene.Node;
    import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
    import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
    import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
    import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
    import javafx.scene.image.Image;
    import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
    import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

    import javafx.stage.DirectoryChooser;
    import javax.naming.Context;
    import testapp.TestApp;

    public class ProjectsController implements Initializable{

        // @FXML private HBox fileList;
        @FXML TreeView<String> Maintree ;
        @FXML private AnchorPane Anchorpane;

         File destinationFolder;



         //Image img = new Image();
         //private final Node rootIcon = new ImageView(img);
    /*  private final Node rootIcon = new ImageView(
                    new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("G:\\workspace\\DefineApp\\src\\images\\folder.png")));*/
         File file = new File("D:\\DefineApp\\src\\images\\folder.png");
            Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString(),20,20,false,false);
            private  Node rootIcon = new ImageView(image);    


         @Override
            public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
             File currentDir = new File("D:\\DefineApp\\src\\Documents"); // current directory
                 rootItem.setExpanded(true);
             Maintree.setShowRoot(false);
                     Maintree.setRoot(rootItem);
                     findFiles(currentDir);
                 try {
                     changeView();
                 } catch (IOException ex) {
                     Logger.getLogger(ProjectsController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                 }
            }


        public void UploadFiles() throws IOException{
            DirectoryChooser directory = new DirectoryChooser();
            directory.setTitle("Choose Directory");

             final File selectedDirectory = directory.showDialog(null);
             File sourcefolder = new File(selectedDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
             String projectName = "Symbiance";
             String studyName = "study1";
             destinationFolder = new File("G:\\workspace\\DefineApp\\src\\"+projectName+"\\"+studyName);

                if(!destinationFolder.exists()){
                    destinationFolder.mkdirs();

                        if(destinationFolder.isDirectory()){
                            // FileUtils.copyDirectory(sourcefolder, destinationFolder);
                             System.out.println("Files Copied Successfully");
                        }
                }else{

                    if(destinationFolder.isDirectory()){
                     //FileUtils.copyDirectory(sourcefolder, destinationFolder);
                     System.out.println("Files Copied Successfully");
                    }

                }
                    //Method call for list the files
                listFiles();
        }

        public void listFiles(){
             //fileList.setPadding(new Insets(15, 12, 15, 12));
             //fileList.setSpacing(10);
            File[] listOfFiles = destinationFolder.listFiles();
            CheckBox[] cbs = new CheckBox[listOfFiles.length];
             int i=0;
            for (File file : listOfFiles) {
                CheckBox cbox = cbs[i]= new CheckBox(file.getName());
                i++;

            }

            //fileList.getChildren().addAll(cbs);
        }

        TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<String>("Root");

        public void findFiles(File currentDir){

             //rootItem.setGraphic(rootIcon);;
            TreeItem<String> subfolder;
             // parent = new TreeItem<String> (parent.getValue(),rootIcon);

            System.out.println("1");
             File folder = new File(currentDir.getAbsolutePath());
                File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
                for (File file:listOfFiles) {           

                    if(file.isDirectory()){
                         subfolder = new TreeItem<String> (file.getName());
                        rootItem.getChildren().add(subfolder);
                        File subFolderName = new File(file.getAbsolutePath());
                        File[] subFolderFiles = subFolderName.listFiles();

                        for(File f:subFolderFiles){
                            TreeItem<String> it= new TreeItem<String>(f.getName());
                            subfolder.getChildren().add(it);
                        }

                    }


                }





        }

        public void changeView() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("change view is called");

                Anchorpane.getChildren().add(TestApp.getInstance().designChooser("com/define/views/AddProject.fxml"));


            //setContent();
        }

     public void addProject(String name,Event e){
         rootItem.getChildren().add(new TreeItem(name));
         System.out.println("test check");
     }

    }

another controller;

package com.define.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class AddProjectController implements Initializable{
    @FXML Button yesbutton;
    @FXML RadioButton projectYesRadio;
    @FXML RadioButton projectNORadio;
    @FXML TextField projectId;
    @FXML TextField projectName;

    final ToggleGroup Projectgroup = new ToggleGroup();
    final File baseFolder = new File("D:\\DefineApp\\src\\Documents");
    File projectFolder;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        projectYesRadio.setToggleGroup(Projectgroup);
        projectNORadio.setToggleGroup(Projectgroup);
        projectYesRadio.setSelected(true);

    }

     public void addProject(ActionEvent e){

             projectFolder = new File("D:\\DefineApp\\src\\Documents\\"+projectName.getText());
             projectFolder.mkdir();
                         ProjectsController pt = new ProjectsController();
                         pt.addProject(projectName.getText(),e);
                          //System.out.println(projectController.Maintree.getRoot());
             //.rootItem.getChildren().add(new TreeItem(projectName.getText()));


         //projectController.findFiles(baseFolder);
         System.out.println("test check");
     }

     public void radiocalled(){
         //yesbutton.setVisible(false);
     }  
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx asks something different, but the solution there has an example of the selection in a `ListView` in one FXML being used in another FXML, which is pretty much identical to what you are asking.